# Learning rate not having an imapct on convergence speed?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

While implementing the behavior of a NAND gate using Rosenblatt's perceptron I was testing the impact of changing the learning rate and how many epochs would it actually need to converge. But changing the value had no impact and the algorithm always converged after 5 epochs.

This is my implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_inputs = 2
epochs = 10 # the loop is written to break once the algorithm converged so this represents max epochs

#binary inputs
training_inputs = np.array([[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]])

#bipolar inputs
#training_inputs = np.array([[1,-1,-1],[1,-1,1],[1,1,-1],[1,1,1]])

d = np.array([1,1,1,-1])
l_rate = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]

for learning_rate in l_rate:
    print('\n====================================\n')
    print('Learning Rate: ',learning_rate)

    w = np.zeros(n_inputs+1)
    previous_w = np.zeros(n_inputs+1)
    conv_epoch = 0

    for i in range(epochs):
        for inputs, targets in zip(training_inputs, d):
            v_i = np.dot(inputs,w)
            if v_i > 0:
                y_i = 1
            elif v_i == 0:
                y_i = 0
            elif v_i < 0:
                y_i = -1
            w = w + learning_rate*(targets - y_i)*inputs


        #logging the weights after each epoch and comparing it to the previous epoch's weights
        print('------------------------')
        print('end of epoch: ',i+1)
        print('weights: ', w)
        print('previous weights: ', previous_w)
        conv = np.array_equal(previous_w, w) #compare to previous epoch's weights to check for convergence
        print('Converged: ',conv)
        if(conv):
            if (conv_epoch==0):
                conv_epoch = i #it converged at the previous epoch
            print('weights: ', w)
            print('Converged at epoch: ',conv_epoch)
            print('------------------------')
            break #after it converged no need to continue with the remaining epochs
        print('------------------------')
        print()
        previous_w = w
```

is this impacted by the nature of the inputs being -1 and 1 or is there anything wrong with my code. I am testing it with both binary and bipolar inputs.